# Emacs Python 3.3 in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, emacs

How to get emacs 24 to use Python 3.3 in Ubuntu 13.04?

When I used

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.3 /usr/bin/python
```

The apt-get update got in trouble (since it apparently depends on python 2.7)

How to change this for emacs?

I also tried

`(setq py-python-command "python3")` as suggested on SO, but this did not work either.

Comment: Please do not down vote without adding a comment for improvement.